# C language to declare a pointer variable, the system will automatically allocate memory? If it's not initialized?

Tags: c

**I am a freshman who has only learned C language**

Statement of int variables at the same time, there was a piece of memory in the computer, if there is no initialization, stored in the memory is rubbish, but still have the memory, my understanding is that statement pointer variable, should also opened up a piece of memory, but if no initialization, stored in the memory is not well-known address (spam), like int variable declaration.

Comment: Answer to the title: no. I can’t understand the body of your question, though. “Plastic” is some kind of mistranslation.

Comment: maybe a new feature? plastic int x = 10;

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73046223/edit) to show an example of the code you have a question about.

Comment: @Ry- That's int .Plastic was translated by machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int a;`
is an uninitialized `int` variable. The compiled code will reserve a piece of memory for that variable. It's content is not specified. It can contain anything when reading it. Reading it is Undefined Behaviour.

`int* b;` is also an unitialized variable, but of type `int*`. the compiled code will also reserve a piece of memory to hold that variable. Since it is a pointer, it has the ability to be dereferenced. However, this pointer is not initialized to a valid address of an `int`.
The same rules apply to pointers here. Reading it before it is initialized invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Only non-static variables are unititialized. Static variables are either explicitly initialized or implicitly zero-initialized.